# Silverpop <ImportList> API error "Mapping Failed. Cannot Import Column: RECIPIENT_ID Unable to continue"

Tags: api

I'm running into the below error

> Mapping Failed. Cannot Import Column: RECIPIENT_ID Unable to continue

I’m using  API method (snippet below), and

```
<Envelope>
    <Body>
        <ImportList><MAP_FILE>ODS_To_Silverpop_Mapping.XML</MAP_FILE>
        <SOURCE_FILE>ODS_To_Silverpop_20170123171113.TXT</SOURCE_FILE></ImportList>
    </Body>
</Envelope>
```

and passing the XML file for mapping information (snippet below), along with the raw data file (not attached here). As per the API documentation, I'm saving these two files in the silverpop FTP folder and making the  API call. This code is working if I don't use the 'RECIPIENT_ID' (which is the auto generated hidden system field) in the mapping xml file (in columns mapping list and in the sync fields list), and use some other key to sync. However, in this specific case, I need too use the RECIPIENT_ID as there is no other reliable field. Does any one have experience with the Silverpop ImportList API method? and thoughts about this issue?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LIST_IMPORT>
    <LIST_INFO>
        <ACTION>ADD_AND_UPDATE</ACTION>
        <LIST_ID>23232323</LIST_ID>
        <FILE_TYPE>0</FILE_TYPE>
        <HASHEADERS>true</HASHEADERS>
    </LIST_INFO>
    <SYNC_FIELDS>
        <SYNC_FIELD>
            <NAME>RECIPIENT_ID</NAME>
        </SYNC_FIELD>
    </SYNC_FIELDS>
    <MAPPING>
        <COLUMN>
            <INDEX>1</INDEX>
            <NAME>Email</NAME>
            <INCLUDE>true</INCLUDE>
        </COLUMN>
        <COLUMN>
            <INDEX>2</INDEX>
            <NAME>RECIPIENT_ID</NAME>
            <INCLUDE>true</INCLUDE>
        </COLUMN>
        <COLUMN>
            <INDEX>3</INDEX>
            <NAME>FirstName</NAME>
            <INCLUDE>true</INCLUDE>
        </COLUMN>
        <COLUMN>
            <INDEX>4</INDEX>
            <NAME>LastName</NAME>
            <INCLUDE>true</INCLUDE>
        </COLUMN>
            <INDEX>5</INDEX>
            <NAME>Last Modified Date</NAME>
            <INCLUDE>false</INCLUDE>
        </COLUMN>
    </MAPPING>
</LIST_IMPORT>
```

Comment: i could not create a new tag 'silverpop-api', so used a generic one

Comment: I know that I can use the <UpdateRecipient> API to update with the RECIPIENT_ID as key, but this will work with single record, but I need to make this work with <ImportList> API as I need bulk import functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Yes In your mapping XML file please Add
`<USE_RECIPIENT_ID>true</USE_RECIPIENT_ID>` inside list_info

below is the snippet

```
<LIST_INFO>
    <ACTION>ADD_AND_UPDATE</ACTION>
    <LIST_ID>23232323</LIST_ID>
    <FILE_TYPE>0</FILE_TYPE>
    <HASHEADERS>true</HASHEADERS>
    <USE_RECIPIENT_ID>true</USE_RECIPIENT_ID>
</LIST_INFO>
```